# I want to keep the program on running until the user enter n to exit the program?

Tags: c++

In the below program, I want to keep the code running until the user enters `n` to stop the program. Can anyone help me do this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,num,f;
    f=1;
    i=1;
    cout<<"Enter a value to get its factorial : ";
    cin>>num;
    while(i<=num)
    {
        f=f*i;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"Factorial of "<<num<<" is "<<f<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Put everything into a loop, and ask for a `std::string` input in first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the do-while loop.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch;
    do{
        int i,num,f;
        f=1;
        i=1;
        cout<<"Enter a value to get its factorial : ";
        cin>>num;
        while(i<=num)
        {
            f=f*i;
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"Factorial of "<<num<<" is "<<f<<endl;
        cout<<"Wanna continue?";
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch != 'n');

}
```

Comment: Make sure to handle the case when `cin >> ... ` fails, such as by bad user input. You will have to use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` to get back in sync.

Comment: Also you should declare f as `long int` or `long long int` since factorial values tend to increase rapidly.

Comment: Thanks dude you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code into a loop and retrieve a `std::string` input to check

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,num,f;
    string input;
    while(1) {
       f=1;
       i=1;
       cout<<"Enter a value to get its factorial or 'n' to exit: ";
       if(cin >> input && input != "n") {
          num = stoi(input);
          while(i<=num)
          {
              f=f*i;
              i++;
          }
          cout<<"Factorial of "<<num<<" is "<<f<<endl;
       }
       else {
           break;
       }
    }
}
```